# Mock out angular.element in Jasmine tests

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

I have a function in a controller that has a call

```
var someVar = angular.element(event.target).scope().field;
```

I am trying to mock it by doing

```
var ngElementFake = function(el) {
                return {
                    scope: function() {
                        return {
                            toggleChildElement: true,
                            field: scope.field
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

spyOn(angular, 'element').andCallFake(ngElementFake);
```

However when I call the function in the test I get the response:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'injector.get('$rootElement').off()')
at ../angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1819
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Injection

```
    beforeEach(function() {
        inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {

            scope = $rootScope;

            scope.record = recordData;

            scope.model = 'Hierarchy';

            ctrl = $controller("fngHierarchyChildCtrl", {
                $scope: scope
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 18):

I was able to fix this by manually clearing the spy in an after callback.

```
var spy;

beforeEach(function() {
    spy = spyOn(angular, 'element').andCallFake(ngElementFake);
});

afterEach(function() {
    spy.andCallThrough();
});
```

Comment: Good one. Works for me

Comment: The important line is `spy.andCallThrough();`

Comment: how to mock `angular` object?

Answer (score 1):

From the AngularJS [FAQ](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq):

> Due to a change to use on()/off() rather than bind()/unbind(), Angular 1.2 only operates with jQuery 1.7.1 or above.

So, try upgrading to jquery 1.7.1 or above or don't use jquery at all and angular will use its own jQLite.

Answer (score 0):

When switching from angular 1.0.8 to 1.2.0, I experienced the following errors when running my tests:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'injector.get('$rootElement').off()')

TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$rootElement.on')
```

The solution was to edit the files section of the karma configuration and move jQuery below angular:

```
 files: [
  //was here
  'http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular.js',
  'http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular-mocks.js',
  'http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular-resource.js',
  'http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular-route.js',
  'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js', //moved to here
  ...
 ]
```